# Can't pass variable from onDataChange to another class/activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pass 2 variables from firebase `onDataChange` method to another activity but always the value is null inside the other activity.

I tried the following things:

- Using a callback interface method to start the start the activity when the async work done
- Checking for null value inside `onDataChange` but always I'm getting the correct value

Can someone help me with this issue?

My database structure:

[image]

My code with the `onDataChange` method inside:

```
public interface FirebaseCallback {
    void onCallback(String callback_userID, String callback_username);
}

void openUserProfile(FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {
    if (!HomeActivity.anonymous) {

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username.getText().toString())) {
                        String uname = username.getText().toString();
                        String userId = snap.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                        firebaseCallback.onCallback(userId, uname);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And I'm calling the `openUserProfile()` like this below:

```
openUserProfile((callback_userID, callback_username) -> {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
   UserProfileActivity.userID = callback_userID;
   UserProfileActivity.username  = callback_username;
   context.startActivity(intent);
   CustomIntent.customType(context, "left-to-right");
 });
```

The `userID` and `username` variables are 2 static variables inside `UserProfileActivityClass`.

Comment: Is `!HomeActivity.anonymous` returning `false`? If not, what are the values of `uname` and `userId` inside `onDataChange`? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo `!HomeActivity.anonymous` is `true` and there is not problem with this if statement. Also `uname` and `userId` have the correct value only inside the `onDataChange`

Comment: If you log the values of `callback_userID` and `callback_username` inside `openUserProfile()` method, what do you get printed out?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm getting the correct values inside `onDataChange`

Comment: And inside openUserProfile()?

Comment: @AlexMamo of course

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried getting the values outside the onDataChange and inside openUserProfile() but I'm not getting the correct value

Comment: Can you add some log statements to your code that show where you get the correct value, and where that is not showing anymore? Once you have that, please add both the updated code and its output to the question.